# FullCalendar plugin - display hour in all of cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using FullCalendar jQuery plugin and I need to modify it. My goal is to automatically display hour in every single cell, in every single day as event. I am creating an online registration system for my application and I need this functionality. After user clicks any hour and confirms it, I want to disable clicks for that chosen hour.

You can see on the picture on Monday example what I want to achive(but for all days):

[image]

Comment: what code are you using? what have you tried?

Comment: But this is the default display...

Comment: I have been trying change this code from four days and now I have no idea how can I makes this work, so I am asking.
@MadalinaTaina I don't know am I write clearly what i want to do :/
Yes It's a default view but I want that events generate automaticly like first three on the picture but in every single cell, in every single day during rendering page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to alter the plugin itself. Just make good use of all of the options available.

If you are just trying to change the content of any event that is displayed on the calendar, pass a function to the [`eventRender` callback](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) that returns a new DOM element. Use the [momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/docs/) to display a formatted string for the `start` property of the event. For example:

```
var calendarOptions = {
   // ...other options
   eventRender: function(event, element) {
     $(element).html(moment(event.start).format('h:mm'));
     return element;
   }
}
```

When you are done with calendarOptions, you'll obviously need to pass it to fullCalendar:

```
$(calElement).fullCalendar(calendarOptions);
```

---

If you want to display an event in every single cell, then first make an array of events for every cell increment... something like this:

```
var myEvents = [];
var timeCursor = moment(startTime);
while (+timeCursor < +moment(endTime)) {
   var start = +timeCursor;
   timeCursor = timeCursor.add(timeIncrement,'minutes');
   var end = +timeCursor;
   myEvents.push({
       start: start, 
       end: end 
   });
}
```

(where you've previously set `startTime`, `endTime`, and `timeIncrement`!)

Then the [`events` property](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_array/) of the calendar options to this array before passing to fullCalendar:

```
calendarOptions.events = myEvents;
```

---

Finally, to handle clicks on an event, pass a function to the [`eventClick` callback option](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) that does whatever you want. For example, if you are keeping track of which events have been clicked, you might want to push their `start` times to an array:

```
var clickedEvents = [];
calendarOptions.eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
    if (clickedEvents.indexOf(calEvent.start) < 0) {
       clickedEvents.push(calEvent.start);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Then of course you might want to modify your `eventRender` callback again to have your event display reflect this status by changing the style of the element, adding a line like this before returning the altered element:

```
if (clickedEvents.indexOf(calEvent.start) < 0) { 
   $(element).addClass('already-clicked');
}
```

(Be sure to set the style for `.already-clicked` in your CSS with something like `cursor: not-allowed` and `opacity: 0.5`.)

fullCalendar rocks!

Comment: Thank You so much for your time! I want to focus about part You write about displaying event in every single cell. I have not tried your code yet because i am completely amateur in jQuery - I just watched some tutorials to understend what it is and also I am completely sure that I will testing your solution during next couple days :) (by the way You explain all very clearly) so I thought that I am ask about details now:

Comment: I have some question for this because i am not sure whether it will work as I expected.
Could You tell me is the array will display events for every single cell in every single day? I mean in this week and next etc? If It does i think that in `startTime` parameter i should put date like this: `moment('2014-05-01T12:00:00');` ? and what about `endTime` parameter, should I leave it empty?

Sorry for my bad spelling :(

Comment: However, the way I've coded it, `startTime` and `endTime` should be strings or numbers that indicate the start and end dates that your calendar is displaying, not actual moment objects, since I pass them to the moment constructor in the code.

Comment: OK, Thanks once again! I will check It tomorrow in my code and let here know how it works :)

Comment: Mr @georgedyer , I will be very grateful if You find some time to look at my answer to your post. I still can't load events created by while loop to my calendar. I think that maybe I have in wrong place code(with creating array) so it makes problem or incorrect date format. I don't know :/ I tryed a lot of ways to resolve this problem but unfortunately I can not. Maybe You will know how to address my issue.

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to use @georgedyer code, but I have some issues :/
Firstly i will show You how it looks like in my MVC 4 application:

Here is my View(html) for display fullCallendar. The point of this is only to display events for every single cell:

```
    //path to installed moment.js
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,


            events: myEvents,

            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                $(element).html(moment(event.start).format('h:mm'));
                return element;
            },

            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.start
                    + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                    + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);

            },

            (...)

    });

    //HERE IS YOUR CODE ABOUT CREATING ARRAY
    var myEvents = [];
    var timeCursor = moment('2015-09-08');
    while (+timeCursor < +moment('2015-10-01'))
    {
        myEvents.push { start: timeCursor }
        timeCursor = timeCursor.add('15', 'minutes');
    }
    </script>

    <div class="container">
    <div id='calendar' style="width:65%"></div>
    </div>
```

I have question about one line of code because VisualStudio display warning here about semicolon: `myEvents.push { start: timeCursor }`. 
I tried to change it to this: `myEvents.push ({ start: timeCursor })`, error disappear, but still doesn't work :/

I don't know what is wrong in this. After run this code It just display empty FullCalendar. I know this code is a little different than your but I think this should work the same way. Please for some help here.

Edit: I think that `eventRender:` function works just fine because if I creating an event by myself,It displays hour like it should. So problem is only in creating events. I think in my code my `myEvents` array is in wrong place and when I invoke it in `events: myEvents` array has zero items.